# string matching using if and split() in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

All,

Can someone explain why the second code doesn't return True?

**1st code**

```
if 'geeta' in 'geetansh':
    print ("True")
else:
    print ("False")
```

Output: `True`

**2nd Code**

```
if 'geeta' in 'geetansh'.split():  
    print ("True")
else:
    print ("False")
```

Output: `False`

What is this particular difference between `'geetansh'` (list) and `'geetansh'.split()` (array) that causes this Mismatch ?

Comment: Why would it split geetansh into ['g', 'e',...] ?

'geetansh'.split() outputs [ 'geetansh']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'geetansh' is a string in python.
So

```
if 'geeta' in 'geetansh':
```

that check whether the string 'geetansh' contain a string 'geeta'.

On the other hand, 'geetansh'.split() is a list in python. split() return a list, so 'geetanch'.split() return ['geetansh']. 
So

```
if 'geeta' in 'geetansh'.split():
```

that check whether the list ['geetansh'] contain a item 'geeta'. The list ['geetansh'] only contain item 'geetansh'.

Answer (score 0):

The basic difference is, str.split() returns a list!

When you compare `a in b`, the comparison is like,

- `b` is a list, then a must be an item in b.
- `b` is a string, then a part of a is in b

That is,

```
>>> 'geeta' in 'geetansh'
True
>>> 'geeta' in 'geetansh'.split()
False
>>> print 'geetansh'.split()
['geetansh']
>>> print type('geetansh'.split())
<type 'list'>
>>> print type('geetansh')
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: Thanks.. I need to work on basics :(

Comment: If you feel a answer suits your question best, you can mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

The `split()` method return an array

```
'geetansh'.split() #return an array ['geetansh']
```

Use this instead:

```
if 'geeta' in 'geetansh'.split()[0]:
    print ("True")
else:
    print ("False")
```

Comment: OP wants it, read his codes

Comment: `split()` doesn't return an [`arrray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) but a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

Answer (score 0):

`'geetansh'.split()` returns a list, `['geetansh']`, so it does not actually contain `'geeta'`.